# My $_POST doesn't get my select name when there is no value

Tags: php, forms, validation, post, input

I am doing a form in PHP where it checks if you inserted your choises, but having problems with multiple choices and arrays, if the Value is empty, the Name isn't even in the $_POST array for me to deal with, unlike other types of input.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$error = 0;
$stored = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){

    if ($key == 'options'){  
        if (empty($value)){
            $error = 1;
         }else {
        foreach ($value as $el) {
            $stored .= $el;            
        }
        }
    } else {
         if (empty($value)){
            $error = 1;
         }else {
         $stored .= $value;
     }

   }
}

if (empty($error)){
   echo $stored . "Sent.";
} else{
    echo 'Error';
  }

}
?>


<form action="form.php" method="post">

    <input name="email" type="email" maxlength="100" class="<?php if ($error == 1 && empty($email)) echo 'borderred';?>"/>

    <select name="options[]" size="3" multiple="multiple"  class="<?php if ($error == 1 && empty($options)) echo 'borderred';?>">
        <option value="one">Option 1</option>
        <option value="two">Option 2</option>
        <option value="three">Option 3</option>
        <option value="four">Option 4</option>
        <option value="five">Option 5</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>    

</body>
</html>

</code>
```

Comment: You can just interpret the missing `key` as an indication that no value is present.

Comment: Great idea! But is there a reason why it goes missing? With other single selects it works just fine, $_POST has the key but not the value

Comment: Standard PHP behaviour is to add the key to the `$_POST` array, but give it an empty value, so your output really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This is an overimplified version of a send email form, I am trying to make those required fields.

Comment: From a functionality point of view, this isn't much of a stumbling block for you. You can just treat missing keys as empty values. But it does make me wonder why you have missing values.

Comment: Basically my problem is the email will be sent even if the user didn't select any of the options, and of course filled other required fields that work just fine. Yes I will follow your adice, thanks.

Comment: Looking at your code, I wouldn't advise cycling through *every* key-value pair. Instead, check for the existing keys and values that you want to set. In the future, you may wish to add entirely optional fields and you want your code to be able to adapt to changes in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with:

```
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) {

    // Do stuff

} else {

    // Do other stuff

}
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answers.

Comment: The other guy in the comments above explained it anyway.